# Integrate row number obtained through variable into cell number

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to integrate a row number obtained by the code below into a cell number for use in getrange(). The first unfiltered row pops up with toast(), so that works.

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var urange = sheet.getRange(2,3,sheet.getLastRow()-1,1);   // Unfiltered range
  var uvals = urange.getDisplayValues();
  var vrow;    // First visible row
  for (let i = 1; i < uvals.length; i++) {
    if (!sheet.isRowHiddenByFilter(i + 1)) {
      vrow = i + 1;
      spreadsheet.toast(`First visible row: ${vrow}`);
      return vrow;
    }
  }
```

I can select a static cell just fine with `spreadsheet.getRange('C2').activate();`, but I'm unable to get the `vrow` variable integrated in this, e.g. `spreadsheet.getRange('C'+vrow).activate();` does not work at all. How can I do this?

I tried multiple notations like `C+vrow`, with and without single quotes, `Cvrow`, `C+${vrow}`, but none select the desired cell.

Thanks

Comment: If the row is hidden because of your filter it can not be activated.  Do you want to unhide?

Comment: I have code that iterates over all visible rows, which is indeed why I want to determine the first visible row, then start operating from that row on.

Comment: I deleted my answer because while I was able to activate the desired cell, I did not fully understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of finding the first unhiden row and activating the cell in column C.

```
function test() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Filter");
    let row = showFirstUnhiddenRow(sheet);
    console.log(`C${row}`);
    sheet.getRange(`C${row}`).activate();
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("Error in test: "+err)
  }
}

function showFirstUnhiddenRow(sheet) {
  try {
    let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    for( let i=2; i<lastRow; i++ ) {
      if( !sheet.isRowHiddenByFilter(i) ) {
        return i;
      }
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("Error in showFirstUnhiddenRow: "+err)
  }
}
```